# GNU make executes weird shell

Tags: make, sh, makefile

The [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) in GNU make behaves weird on Ubuntu. Consider this simple Makefile:

```
TEST1 := $(shell command -v sh)
TEST2 := $(shell /bin/sh -c 'command -v sh')
all:
        $(info TEST1 = $(TEST1))
        $(info TEST2 = $(TEST2))
```

Running `make` prints

```
make: command: Command not found
TEST1 = 
TEST2 = /usr/bin/sh
```

Weird. Why does the default shell not know the `command` built-in? And what is the default shell invoked by GNU make actually? According to the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell):

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL. If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell.

There is no `SHELL` variable in the Makefile above, so the shell should be `/bin/sh`. However, running `/bin/sh` explicitly from the default shell actually behaves as expected, so there must be some difference.

So what is the real problem? It seems to be specific to GNU make packaged in Ubuntu, since the aforementioned Makefile behaves as expected on other systems like Arch Linux (which symlinks `/bin/sh` to `bash` rather than `dash`, though), i.e. it prints `TEST1 = /usr/bin/sh`.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Based on `strace` output it seems not to use a shell at all (instead passing the command + args to `execve` directly), either when make variable `SHELL` is undefined **or** set to `/bin/sh`. It seems to be possible to trick it into using `sh` on systems where /bin and /usr/bin are symlinked by setting `SHELL=/usr/bin/sh`.

Comment: Arch Linux also symlinks `/bin` to `/usr/bin` and it works just fine, with and without `SHELL := /bin/sh`. So what's the difference between using `SHELL := /bin/sh` and `SHELL := /usr/bin/sh` on Ubuntu?

Comment: In my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS system, `/bin/sh` is symlinked to *bash* and `/usr/bin/sh` does not exist. At one time, I think `/bin/sh` may have been symlinked to *dash* and `/usr/bin/sh` may have been *bash*. I'd have to confirm that.